# Automatic relevance determination in multi-output coregionalized Gaussian process

Tags: gaussian-process, importance

I've set up a multi task Gaussian process problem with the help of coregionalization (more precise: an **intrinsic coregionalization model (ICM)**). My features space constists of ~20 input dimensions for six outputs. Following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.6251) the kernel matrix $\mathbf{K}$ corresponding to a dataset $\mathbf{X}$ takes the form

$$\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{X, X}) = \mathbf{B} \otimes k(\mathbf{X, X})$$

$k(\mathbf{X, X})$ is here a GP kernel of choice possibly able to do **Automatic Relevance Determination (ARD)**. In my case, $k(\mathbf{X, X})$ is a rational quadratic kernel, exploiting its lengthscale for ARD. $\mathbf{B}$ is the coregionalization matrix, $\otimes$ the kronecker product.

According to the paper, I understand that $k(\mathbf{X, X})$ models the input dependence, independently of the particular set of outputs, while $\mathbf{B}$ models the dependence between the outputs, indepently of the inputs.

Training the model and modelling the outputs works. I am now interested in the feature relevance / input sensitivity of the input features for each output individually. I assume that the lengthscales of $k(\mathbf{X, X})$, after training, somehow reflect the input feature importance for **all** outputs together.

I am wondering if there is a way to combine the information carried by $\mathbf{B}$ with the info carried by $k(\mathbf{X, X})$ to obtain a set of most important features for **each** output individually?

(The technical implementation is done with the python `GPy.models.GPCoregionalizedRegression` class of package `GPy`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand, with this type of model the implicit assumption is that all of your outputs are determined by the *same* "underlying" or "latent" Gaussian Process.

The "relevance" of the input features should consequently be identical for each output, since the underlying covariance structure with respect to $X$ will be the same (the latent GP).

Comment: Thanks, you've been absolutely right. For the ICM model, all outputs share the same latent GP. I did some further research and came up with an LCM model (linear coregionalized model), which is a generalization of the ICM, where you have a latent GP for each individual output and thus can estimate the feature significance per output.